# Have Matlab figures docked by default

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In Matlab, it is possible to have figure windows docked in the main window.  If there are several figures, each of them appears in a different "tab".

Is it possible to set up the system so that all figure windows will be created docked by default?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To [dock figures by default](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/docking-figures-in-the-desktop.html#f5-43317), try calling:

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','docked')
```

at the beginning

Comment: You may consider adding the above command to [startup.m](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html) or create a [shortcut](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2007/03/29/shortcuts-for-commonly-used-code/).

Comment: @zellus: good advice, I already have these two shortcuts in my IDE: one `set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','docked')`, the other `set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','normal')`

Answer (score 1):

The point 'n' click alternative:

Click `Desktop` -> `Figures`.

Click the arrow underneath the cross in the top-right (tooltip is 'Dock Figures').

Save your desktop layout with `Desktop` -> `Save Layout...`